# Convert a string with array-like content to a 2D array

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I have an input type element where I enter the array indices to be set to true.
The input returns a string. However if it returns a 2D array it would be fine.
So I want to know how to convert the string to an array.

```
var mystr= "[[1,2],[2]]";
typeof(mystr); // returns string.
```

I would like to know how to convert this into a 2D array using a function like below

```
myarray = Convert2Array(mystr);
```

so that I can iterate it in a way like

```
var i,j;
for(i=0;i<rownum;i++){
    for(j=0;j<colnum;j++){
        myarray [i][j];
    }
}
```

But I am not able to figure out how `Convert2Array()` should be written.

Comment: So the user of your page is required to enter `[['1','2'],['2']]` into an input box?

Comment: This looks like JSON code. You could use a JSON parser to create a multidimensional array out of it.

Comment: What it should be the format of those numbers? String or Number?

Comment: @MarcoCI  it is numbers....I am editing the post

Comment: You can just pass the string to [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse). The drawback here is that [the JSON object does not exist in IE6/7](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc836458(v=vs.94).aspx). If you don't care about those old browsers, then you can just ignore that little caveat.

Comment: That's easily fixed by [conditionally](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) including [JSON2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) for these browsers.

Comment: @Tomalak True, although JSON2 is written such that you don't have to conditionally include it. It leaves the native `JSON` object alone if it exists.

Comment: @ajp15243 True, although why unconditionally load a library that you don't need in 90% of all cases. ;)

Comment: @Tomalak True (this is ridiculous lol), but it's a nice feature if you build all of your JS into a single file.

Comment: @ajp15243 \*sigh\* :) Yes, that's indeed so. I think we both made our points.

Answer (score 0):

Try just parsing it as JSON

```
var myarray = JSON.parse(mystr);
```

This should be supported in most modern browsers